# Can't edit -rwxrwxrwx file on solaris

Tags: unix, permissions, vi

I created a file:

```
touch script.sh
```

changed it's permissions:

```
chmod 777 script.sh
```

which gave the following permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 foouser staff          0 Aug 18 15:41 script.sh
```

... but when I attempt to edit in vi I get a permissions error:

```
"script.sh" File is read only
```

Why is this?

Comment: What says `echo date >> script.sh`?

Comment: That allows me to write to the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I figured out that someone had set:

```
alias vi=view
```

So doing `unalias vi` fixed the problem...